# Do I need to use Prisma's connect & disconnect API? Or is it not safe to just update my Relations via IDs as strings?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prisma, planetscale

I am using prisma + mysql (on planetscale). When I link two items that are in different tables, I normally use `connect` or `disconnect`:

```
const getUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    id: 9
  },
  data: {
    posts: {
|      connect: {
|        id: 11
|      },
      create: {
        title: "My new post title"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I am wondering whether that's necessary or why that's necessary?

I also noticed that I can just update records in my database by updating the id (as a plain string), and it will still work. e.g.:

```js
// example for updating a one-to-many relationship:
const getUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    id: 9
  },
  data: {
    postId: "123192312i39123123"
    }
  }
})
```

... or if it's an explicit many-to-many relation, I can just edit the row in the relation-table & update the id.

Is this a bad way of doing things? Am I going to break something later down the line in doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Your cloud provider is not relevant in the context of the question. It will not affect how your framework(prisma) behaves in updates.

> I am wondering whether that's necessary or why that's necessary?

You have a user with a one to many relation: `user => n posts`.
You have an existing post in the db, and you want to add that post to the posts collection of a user.

That posts relation can be either explicit or implicit. The `connect` clause handles the addition of relation:

```js
{
  posts: {
    connect: { id: 11 }
  }
}
```

Without using the `connect` you'd have to create a new post:

```js
{
  posts: {
    create: {
      title: "My new post title"
    }
  }
}
```

> update records in my database by updating the id (as a plain string)

Not sure what you mean here, mind sharing the schema?

> or if it's an explicit many-to-many relation, I can just edit the row in the relation-table & update the id

If it's explicit many-to-many then it's OK to manually edit the id fields. As long as the ids are found and the relation makes sense, there's no problem with manual updates.

Answer (score 0):

While you can manually update IDs, using `connect` and `disconnect` has a few advantages:

- **First and foremost, `connect` throws an exception if any of the connected records do not exist.**

  Because Prisma supports multiple DBs, I assume they do this check in their own engine, rather than relying on the DB to check the foreign key constraint.
- It can be used to update a specific entity plus one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships with a single interface and without having to write a separated query for the junction table:

  ```
  const result = await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      email: 'user@domain.com',
    },
    data: {
      lastSeen: Date.now(),
      featuredPost: {
        connect: { id: 8 },
      },
    },
  })

  const result = await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      email: 'user@domain.com',
    },
    data: {
      lastSeen: Date.now(),
      posts: {
        connect: [{ id: 8 }, { id: 9 }, { id: 10 }],
      },
    },
  })
  ```
- You can also use [`connectOrCreate`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connectorcreate) to easily create an entity if it doesn't exist already.
- For `disconnect`, you also have single interface that works with one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, and you can easily disconnect all related records too:

  ```
  const result = await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
      email: 'user@domain.com',
    },
    data: {
      posts: {
        set: [],
      },
    },
  })
  ```

You can read more in the [officials docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#connect-multiple-records).