# Prisma create -> connect vs id in data object

Tags: prisma

I have a Prisma schema that resembles the one below

```
model Group {
  id    String @id
  items Item[]
}

model Item {
  id      String @id
  groupId String
  group   Group @relation(fields: [groupId ], references: [id])
  value   String
}
```

When creating a new `Item`, I can link a `Group` either by setting the `groupId` as part of the `data` object or by using the `connect` parameter. E.g.:

```
// Approach 1: using the data object directly
prisma.item.create({
  data: {
    id: "abc",
    value: "dummy",
    groupId: "xyz"
  }
})

// Approach 2: using the connect parameter
prisma.item.create({
  data: {
    id: "abc",
    value: "dummy",
    group: {
      connect: {
        id: "xyz"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

In the docs Prisma seems to advocate for using the `connect` parameter. What are the advantages of using `connect` over setting the `groupId` property in the `data` object directly?

P.s.: I'm working on multiple projects using Prisma and they are using either Postgres or sqlite

Comment: I think you can find your answer on [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567991/15965186)